Approximate continuous functions by "partially injective" functions.
In Munkres book Topology, Theorem 50.5, page 311, the author gives the following definition in a proof.

Let $f:X\to \Bbb R^n$ be a continuous function where $X$ is a compact metric space. Define $$\Delta(f)=\sup\{\operatorname{diam}f^{-1}(\{z\}):z\in f(X)\}.$$

And he claimed that the number $\Delta(f)$ measures how far $f$ "deviates" from being injective, which is not really clear to me, as for example taking $X=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=x^2$ then the diameter is $2$ at $z=1$, which is the maximum that functions deefined on $[-1,1]$ could possible be, while one could "oscillates" $f$ inside more to create "less injectivity". But that is fine for now as it hasn't been proved to be useful, but then I encountered a contradiction at one of his problems, quoted below.

Suppose that $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis, such that every compact subspace of $X$ has topological dimension at most $m$. Let $N=2m+1$. Given $X\to \Bbb R^N$ a continuous map and a compact subspace $C$ of $X$, define $$U_{\varepsilon}(C)=\{f:\Delta(f|_C)<\epsilon\}.$$ Show that $U_\varepsilon(C)$ is dense in $C(X,\Bbb R^N)$.

This is exercise $6$, question $(d)$ on page 315. But if I were to take $f(x)=x^2$ while $X=\Bbb R$, $C=[-1,1]$ I really doubt one could approximate $f$ with functions in $U_\varepsilon([-1,1])$. Intuitively functions in $U_\varepsilon([-1,1])$ are "partially monotonic" functions possibly with little oscillations at some places where the diameter of this oscillation domain would not exceed $\epsilon$. If one could choose a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $U_\varepsilon([-1,1])$ to approximate $f(x)=x^2$, then the diameter of the fiber $f_n^{-1}(\{1\})$ of this sequence of functions should really be getting closer to $2$, while $\varepsilon$ could be arbitary small.
Where am I wrong about this? Could anyone provides a thought of where I was wrong?

Is your example right?  For the map $x^2$ on ${0,1}$ I'd say the diameter was $0$ since the map is injective on that set.  Maybe you meant something like $x(x-1)$.  That has diameter $1$.

In your example, $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$, we have $f^{-1}({1}) = {1}$, so the diameter of the preimage of this point is $0$.  In fact this $f$ is injective, and so $\Delta(f) = 0$.

@lulu Sorry! I made a typo.

@ChrisEagle Corrected!

Post edit, still wrong.  With $X$ now ${-1,1}$ the diameter is $2$.

@lulu Thank you! Corrected!

About the definition in general, there are a lot of ways you could say "how injective" a function is.  The basic template would be to say that a function is "very non-injective" if there is a point $z$ where $f^{-1}({z})$ is a "large" set in some sense.  In this definition we're using the metric to define "large"; when $\Delta(f)$ is large it means that there are points that are far apart in the space that get mapped to the same place. You could make up other definitions of "large" (maybe based on cardinality, or measure, or Baire category, or whatever) depending on your intended application

As to the exercise, $m=1$ here, yes?  So you need a map to $\mathbb R^3$.  I agree that $x\mapsto x^2$ can't be so approximated, but the dimension is off.

@lulu Yes I realized that. I think I will leave the question here for now while I re-think about this.

@lulu That makes sense. You can post an answer and I will accept it.

Well, I don't have an answer to the underlying exercise (haven't thought about it in depth).

@lulu I believe my question is about where I was wrong in my explanation paragraph. Pointing it out is already a satisfying answer. Feel free to post an answer if you would like to.
